# Angenieux 6-80mm Super 8 lens "40/80" knob

Tags: lens, film

I'm new to the world of film.  My Beaulieu 5008-s came with the Angenieux 6-80mm f/1.2 lens.  About half way up the barrel there is a small knob engraved with "40" along the edge and "80" directly across from it.  I am wondering what it's purpose is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: This could be numerology, but I can't help notice the coincidence of the "80" marking and the maximum focal length of the lens. Could it be some zoom range limiting device or even some lock in preset positions?